# Tensorflow Estimator.predict_scores not yielding the correct number of predictions when using the Dataset API in the input function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am using tensorflow 1.5 and I am puzzled by this strange behavior that I can't explain.
I produced a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def input_function(x, y, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, n_epochs=None):
    data_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"x": x, "y": y})
    if shuffle:
        data_set = data_set.shuffle(buffer_size=1024, seed=None, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
    data_set = data_set.batch(batch_size)
    data_set = data_set.repeat(n_epochs)
    iterator = data_set.make_one_shot_iterator()
    example = iterator.get_next()
    return {"features": example["x"]}, example["y"]


def main():
    n_samples = 256
    n_features = 16
    n_labels = 1

    x = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_features).astype(np.float32)
    y = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_labels).astype(np.float32)

    feature_column = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(column_name='features', dimension=n_features)
    estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor([10], [feature_column], optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer())

    estimator.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_function(x, y, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, n_epochs=32))
    pred = estimator.predict_scores(input_fn=lambda: input_function(x, y, batch_size=16, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1))
    print("len(pred) = {} (should be {})".format(len(list(pred)), n_samples))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this example, the call to 'fit' seems to be working fine (I'm not sure though) but the call to 'predict_scores' only produces batch_size (=16) predictions instead of n_samples (=256). What I am doing wrong ?
This problem disappears if I use the tf.esimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn although eventually I'll have to use an input function that uses a TFRecordDataset to read a large amount of training data from tfrecord files, similarly to what is showed here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#using_high-level_apis
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` class, which incorrectly assumes that the [input is constant](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4faee3942d9983e0c96091b32095cc0d9ff494e0/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L976), and only reads one batch, instead of running the input function multiple times to get all of the data. The `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` and `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor` classes are deprecated and slated for removal, so it is unlikely that they will be fixed.

However, the [`tf.estimator.DNNRegressor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNRegressor) class has been fixed to work with `tf.data`, and you can modify your code to use it as follows:

```
def main():
    n_samples = 256
    n_features = 16
    n_labels = 1

    x = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_features).astype(np.float32)
    y = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_labels).astype(np.float32)

    feature_column = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(
        column_name='features', dimension=n_features)

    # Use the `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` constructor instead of
    # `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor`.
    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
        [10], [feature_column], optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer())

    # Replace `estimator.fit()` with `estimator.train()`.
    estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: input_function(
        x, y, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, n_epochs=32))

    # Replace `estimator.predict_scores()` with `estimator.predict()`.
    pred = estimator.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_function(
        x, y, batch_size=16, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1))

    print("len(pred) = {} (should be {})".format(len(list(pred)), n_samples))
```